# PostgreSQL : question about SELECT .. WHERE .. = max()

Tags: postgresql, postgis-2.0

If you have, for example;

```
SELECT * FROM data 
WHERE line = min( (SELECT length FROM lines) ) 
      AND number < 500;
```

(It's just an example, not a real code)

How does PostgreSQL react when the result from the MIN has a number > 500 ? Is he then going after the second MIN or what happens ?

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by line = length?

I guess what you mean is that your subquery will find the id of the shortest line. Then you ask in the outer query for a line with that id and some number less than 500. If the shortest line then have a a number that is more than 500 you will get nothing back.

**EDIT**

Something like this should work if I understand you right.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id , geom
FROM lines_table 
WHERE some_number < 500 
ORDER BY id, ST_Length(geom);
```

Comment: thank you! and how can I achieve this? Select the line with the highest length, but with other conditions (like the number <500, for example)